# How to create variable from mobile element?

Tags: java, android, appium

I am attempting an automated test using appium java, and trying to create a variable for an element, but the test always fail.

If i do the following:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("android:id/message")))
```

it will print the text from the box.

If i attempt the followings, a "NoSuchElement" error will be displayed:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("android:id/message"));
System.out.println(element.getText());
```

or

```
MobileElement element = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.id("android:id/message"));
System.out.println(element.getText());
```

How should i declare a variable in order to be used later on the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("android:id/message"));
String print = element.getText();
System.out.println("Print my text " + print);
```

Comment: Ok, this works for print, but, as i told @Apurva, I would like to click buttons as well, example: WebElement but = driver.findElement(By.id("android:id/button"));
but.click();
Atm, click does not work for me... any idea on how to solve that one?